# Use Picasso loading thread without caching

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a drawable resource that I want to load a bunch of rows in a RecyclerView.  The resource, however, is transformed into different colors for every row.  So, I want to use Picasso here for all the niceties it provides in loading with the adapter and the Tranformation interface (to color the image).

The problem is that the image is then cached by Picasso after the first Tranformation, so all the images end up having the same color in the RecyclerView.

Is there a nice way to get Picasso to reload the Transformation for all these images, so they all have their different respective Transformations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

In Tranformation:

```
/**
 * Returns a unique key for the transformation, used for caching purposes. If the transformation
 * has parameters (e.g. size, scale factor, etc) then these should be part of the key.
 */
 String key();
```

I was supposed to put my unique identifiers (the color of my image in this case) in the key of the Transformation.

Thanks for a great API, Square Picasso team!

Extra thanks to the great Jake Wharton for correcting my original naive answer.

Comment: This is not the right solution. From the sound of your question, you are not including the color in the transformation key.

Comment: @JakeWharton Oh, if I use the color as the Transformation key, then it should work?  I apologize I did not read the Tranformation doc well enough.